# Is it possible to move a Conan package from conan-center to a private registry on an air-gapped network?

Tags: conan

Is it possible to move a Conan package from conan-center to a private registry on an air-gapped network?

I'm working with an air-gapped network and would like to "export" open source packages from conan-center and move them to my private remote on an air gapped network.

Comment: What do you mean by private registry? Artifactory, Conan Server? I can say you can use the mirror feature from Artifactory, where you can download from Bintray (Conan Center) and after that, install from a standalone Artifactory.

Comment: Take a look about Artifactory here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html. And, about Bintray integration https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? If so, did you end up using Artifactory?